# Has anyone seen this series?

Tags: pr.probability, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, special-functions

I come across the following infinite series.

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{t^n}{n!\: n^{a}}, \quad\text{for $t>0$ and $a>0$}.
$$

In particular, I am interested in the case where $a=1/4$.

Thanks for any hints and references!

Anand

Comment: I somehow suspected a "Wanted dead or alive" like poster when I first read the title...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For natural values of *a*, take $\displaystyle\frac{e^t-1}t=\sum_1^\infty\dfrac{t^{n-1}}{n!}$, then apply the operator $\bigg(\displaystyle\frac1t\cdot\int\bigg)$ *a* times to it. For $a\not\in\mathbb N$, such as $a=\dfrac14$, welcome to the “marvelous” world of [fractional calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus) and [Riemann-Liouville integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann-Liouville_integral).

---

For natural values of *a*, the series can also be expressed in terms of the ([generalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function)) [hypergeometric function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) $_{a+1}{\large F}_{a+1}\bigg(\underbrace{1,1,\ldots,1}_{a+1}~;~\underbrace{2,2,\ldots,2}_{a+1}~;~t\bigg)$.

Comment: Thanks Lucian for your answer. I am interested in the case where a is between 0 and 1. I don't see how the fractional calculus can bring $n^a$ to the denominator, rather some Gamma functions. Could you please give more hints on this case? Thanks a lot!

Comment: For $a\in(0,1)$, squeeze it in between $f_0(t)=e^t-1$ and $f_1(t)=Ei(t)-\ln t-\gamma$. See [exponential integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral). Also, if $f_a(t)=t\cdot\bigg(\dfrac1t\displaystyle\int\bigg)^a\circ \bigg(\dfrac{e^t-1}t\bigg)$ for natural *a*, then I'm assuming the same should also hold true for $a\not\in\mathbb N$. I'd be surprised if it wouldn't.

Comment: If you interpret your $(\int)^{1/4}$ by the fractional integral $J^{1/4}$ as in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus, what your get for $t^n$ is $J^{1/4} t^n = \frac{t^{n+1/4}n!}{\Gamma(n+1/4)}$. We cannot get $n^{1/4}$ in the denominator.

Comment: $\displaystyle\sum_1^\infty\frac{t^n}{n!~n^a}{\large\approx} \sum_1^\infty\frac{t^n}{(n+a)!}$ for $a=\dfrac14$

Comment: Thanks Lucian! Do you know how good is this approximation? Good upper and lower bounds will also be great! I will do some calculations tomorrow. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maximum relative error of about $10-15$% at $t=0$, decreasing exponentially towards $0$ as *t* increases.

Comment: Well you can also substitute $t=e^x$ and then integrate  1/4 times *wrt $x$*...

Comment: Glad to hear that, @Anand! :-) Though now I realize that the same approximation could also have been derived from [Stirling's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation).