# How to integrate an exponential function of an exponential function?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sequences-and-series, integration, stochastic-calculus, integral-transforms

Does any one know how to calculate the following integration?

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} \left(\exp(z \: e^{-y^2})-1\right)^2 dy=?,\quad z>0.
$$

This post is related to my previous question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/161068/has-anyone-seen-this-series) , based on which one can have a upper bound. Can any one give an exact solution for this integration?

Thanks a lot!
Anand

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can expand the integrand in powers of z. The coefficient of $z^k$ is
$$e^{-ky^2}\sum_{j=1}^{k-1} {1\over j!(k-j)!}=e^{-ky^2}(2^k-2)/k!.$$
This yields the following series expression for the integral:
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sqrt{\pi\over k}(-2+2^k)z^k/k!.$$

Answer (score 1):

A complementary approach is to consider the limit $z \to +\infty$. Based on the shape of the integrand, the overwhelming contribution should come from the vicinity of $y=0$, where only the highest order term $\exp(2z e^{-y^2}) \sim e^{2z} \exp(-2zy^2)$ will contribute significantly. Doing the Gaussian integral gives the leading term of the large $z$ asymptotic expansion: $e^{2z}/\sqrt{2z/\pi}$. A more systematic approach would go through [Laplace's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method), which I believe would yield the same leading term.

Comment: So the answer is in terms of the function $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!\sqrt{k}}.$$ Has it explicit form?

Comment: Sergei, I don't think that it has an explicit form. See my previous post: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/161068/has-anyone-seen-this-series